# How do I send value from arduino to a web form

Tags: rest, web, arduino, at-command

I need to send a string from the arduino to the web form on that page https://vibrant-bastille-64033.herokuapp.com/ and submits the form.
This is the current code of my arduino, what is wrong, or what is missing..

```
void SubmitHttpRequest()
{
mySerial.println("AT+CSQ");
delay(100);

ShowSerialData();// this code is to show the data from gprs shield, in order to easily see the process of how the gprs shield submit a http request, and the following is for this purpose too.

mySerial.println("AT+CGATT?");
delay(100);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");//setting the SAPBR, the connection type is using gprs
delay(5000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet.vodafone.net \"");//setting the APN, the second need you fill in your local apn server
delay(8000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");//setting the SAPBR, for detail you can refer to the AT command mamual
delay(5000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");//setting the SAPBR, for detail you can refer to the AT command mamual
delay(8000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM"); //term the HTTP request

delay(5000); 

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT"); //init the HTTP request

delay(5000); 
ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"vibrant-bastille-64033.herokuapp.com/create\"");// setting the httppara, the second parameter is the website you want to access
delay(5000);

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPDATA=1000,10000"); //100 refers to how many bytes you're sending.  You'll probably have to tweak or just put a large #
  delay(10000);
ShowSerialData();
  mySerial.println("[\"id\": \"01\",\"current_value\": \"" "\",");
delay(500);
  mySerial.println("TEST from Arduino"); //ie latitude,longitude,etc...
 delay(5000);
ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=1");//submit the request 
delay(5000);//the delay is very important, the delay time is base on the return from the website, if the return datas are very large, the time required longer.
while(!mySerial.available());

ShowSerialData();

mySerial.println("finish");
delay(100);

mySerial.println("[\"id\": \"01\",\"current_value\": \"" "\",");
delay(500);
ShowSerialData();
}
```

Comment: What GSM/GPRS module are you using?

Comment: It's called: SIM808